# The second Particles System not working Properly

Tags: particles

I am building up a firework scene after watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6SZp77VNqM). However, some problem turns up when I set up the second Particle System. In the tutorial, the second particles emission from the first ones. But when I tried it out, it is not so. My second particles was a line of cubes(at the cursor of the picture). I changed a lot of setting, but it never works like in the tutorial.
[image]
Blender version:2.77a

OS System:UbuntuStudio

My blender file is uploaded to GDrive, [Download it if you need it](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0gXVivxuIBtWFRMWjNNd3pvQ2M).
Don't care about the stuffs in the first layer;)

Comment: I can't sift through it right now, but this other tutorial looks like it's doing the same thing, but with a newer version of Blender. See if this one reveals what the problem is... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9vceDdTufo

Comment: @Matt  But in this tutorial it set three particle systems--same as the video I watched.

Comment: @Matt in the video above at about 11:18, after he settled the third particles, when he play the animation, a line of stuffs drop off just like mine, but there are small stuffs come behind the first particle system. Can the phenomenon be explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be 2 particle systems on the object (there's only one in your file). The second particle system modifier should be in the bottom of the stack.

[image: screenshot of creating new particle system]

You will setup it as desired, the main option to change would be start and end frame.
Starting frame should be *roughly* the same as the end frame of the first system. Values from the lesson didn't work well so I changed them - while particles of first system die at frame 26, particles of the second one burn at 23.

However to make second particle system emit particles from the faces exploded by the Explode modifier you should enable [*Use Modifier Stack*](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/emission.html#options) option:

[image: screenshot of second particle system settings]

The reason this wasn't mentioned in tutorial is because [*Use Modifier Stack* option was added starting from version 2.68](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.68/Physics).

[image: particle-system-fireworks_GIF]