# Baking of several particle systems

Tags: particles

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dTcz5wWvVE) tutorial. have two particle systems in my scene (for the same object). One particle system is for generating shards of glass and the other one for smoke & fire. I should say that I should do two bakes, one for each particle system. Is that right ?

I think I am a bit confused about the "baking" options.

A) Particle System "Shards of Glass". As I said I have one particle system for generating shards of glass. The particle system uses "shards of glass" objects. In the "particle system" box there is an option to bake. This is to bake the emission of shards of glass ?

B) Smoke and Fire Simulation. A cube is used for the "domain" and a  particle system for the "flow" of smoke and fire. When dealing with smoke and fire in tutorials the baking is done in the domain (but why not in the particle system)? Why is that ? Why is the baking not done in the particle system (the particle system emits the smoke) ?

I guess I have a basic non-understanding about all these baking options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, particle systems are responsible for emitting particles, they have nothing to do with any smoke or fire simulations; on the other hand, smoke simulation is used for emitting smoke, not for particles. Particle system can be used as emitter for smoke (instead of actual mesh), - but their data is different and you can't bake smoke simulation from particle system panel (unless baking *everything*, see below).

Hence there is *Bake* button for baking in their options. It will work per each physics simulation - each smoke / fire sim will be baked from its domain, particle systems - from their options per each particle system, same for dynamic paint etc. With this way you'll bake them one by one.

[image: screenshot of baking panel]

The only way which is independant on these options is to bake all physics at once - with [*Bake All Dynamics*](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/baking.html) button which will bake everything you have to bake in scene:

> **Bake All Dynamics**
>       Bake all physics systems in the scene, even those of different types. Useful for baking complex setups involving interactions between different physics types.

*Note that it may last longer than you expected (because of amount of data to compute).*

Comment: I understand that the baking of smoke/fire is done in the physics domain. But this "emission of shards of glass" ...does this need baking ?And if yes, is it done in the particle systems box ?

Comment: A second question ... "bake all dynamics" is an option for one particle system. Does this bake all physics, also for other particle systems ? I guess the answer is yes, but it is a bit strange ...

Comment: Can you give an example of baking a particle system that is not a physics simulation (like smoke/fire) ?

Comment: @OldMan baking is needed for any type of simulation used in the scene. If it isn't done it will be calculated while playing animation (hence slower / increasing possibility of crash etc)  If "shards of glass" were done with particle system , then find that particle system making those shards and bake from there - you'll bake only physics responsible for those shards of glass. If any other system depends on those shards, that system will be needed to be calculated. Your second question - yes, for all other particle systems (and not only). Not sure what you mean by the last question

Comment: by the way (maybe the is a new question) ... I just bumped into this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56514/the-second-particles-system-not-working-properly?rq=1 answered by you. I understand you can apply a particle system in conjunction with an explode modifier. In the tutorial that I am doing the particle systems emits shards of glass and not pieces created by the explosion. What is best ?

Comment: ok ... I will make another question. I still don't complete understand the baking. A) why is the baking for smoke/fire done under the physics tab and not under the particle system tab ? B) a bit strange that when you click "bake all dynamics" all bakes are done, also for other particle systems ?

Comment: A. When baking with *Bake* button it must be done per each physics simulation. As smoke sim settings are in physics tab, you control them from there. And bake from there too. Particle systems have their control panel in their own tab; and they are being baked from there. So for object with 3 particle systems and smoke sim you'll have to open 1st system, hit Bake, open 2nd, bake there, open 3rd, bake there, then select domain, open Physics tab for it and bake from there. B. in this case all these operations are done for you automatically (has disadvantages too)

Comment: @OldMan In other words- baking particles mean pre-calculating only particles. Baking smoke sim based on particles means only baking smoke sim (you'llbe able to change system's settings). It's enough to bake only smoke sim as generally particles system takes far less resources than smoke.

Comment: I think now I get it. Thx